# PHPickerViewController not showing Photo Stream

Tags: ios, phpickerviewcontroller, photostream

We use `PHPickerViewController` to allow the user to pick photos to import into our app. Recently a user said they do not see their Photo Stream in the picker.

Is there a way to get the Photo Stream album to show in a `PHPickerViewController`?

Answer (score 0):

We had 2 customers reporting the same problem and I personally faced the problem on my device.

It wasn't limited to a single app. Even if I created a new app, the PHPickerViewController didn't work for it.

There were no errors in the debug console. The only message appeared after presenting PHPickerViewController was "Successfully load keyboard extensions".

PHPickerViewController appeared after a 3-4 seconds delay with only "Cancel" button and "Loading..." label present.

Device restart solved the problem on my device.